# Выборка и дальнейшая запись из одного json объекта в другой json

Tags: javascript, json

Имеется `json` объект вида

```
data: {
    "competense":"1.2.4.\t Текст"
},
...
```

Где текст внутри `competense` начинается с разного уровня `1.`,`1.3`,`1.3.1`

Как мне отыскать только тот `copmpetense` c первым уровнем вида `1.`, `2.`  и поместить в другой `json` объект с другой структурой где каждое значение текста с первым уровнем будет записано в `name`.

**Обновление**

Пример:

1. Текст1
   1.1. Текст1
   1.2. Текст1
2. Текст2
   2.1 Текст2
3. Текст3

Каждый элемент хранится в объекте. Нужно выбрать элементы кторые только первого уровня

1. Текст1
2. Текст2
3. Текст3

И записать их в другой объект json вида

```
data: [{
    name: "1 .Текст1",
    y: 56.33
}, {
    name: "2 .Текст2",
    y: 24.03,

}, {
    name: "3 .Текст3",
    y: 10.38
}]
```

часть объекта:

```
var ret =[{
    "fios":[{"FIO":"Иванов Иван","ID":"24990"},{"FIO":"Иванов Иван","ID":"24895"},{"FIO":"Иванов Иван","ID":"25004"}],
    "sum":190,
    "user":[],
    "competense":"1.\tМатериаловедение и контроль качества материалов"}
,
    {"fios":[{"FIO":"Иванов Иван","ID":"24990"},{"FIO":"Иванов Иван","ID":"24895"},{"FIO":"Иванов Иван","ID":"25004"}],
"sum":91,
"user":[],
"competense":"1.1.\tРазработка, исследование, аттестация и сертификация конструкционных материалов (основных, сварочных и наплавочных):"}];
```

Comment: Было бы проще если бы вы написали пример, который пояснял бы ваши слова

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго дня!

Перебрать в цикле все значения json, в цикле поставить условие на совпадение регулярному выражению, и если условие выполняется делать запись в новый json.

Comment: Немного не пойму как организовать цикл поиска. По каким критериям можно найти цифры только первого уровня

Comment: `var arr = [{fio: 'AAA', competense: '1.3.\tgggg'}, 
           {fio: 'BBB', competense: '1.\ttttt'},
          {fio: 'CCC', competense: '1.3.2.\tbbbb'},
          {fio: 'DDD', competense: '2.\tgggg'}];

var newArr = [];

var myRe = new RegExp("^[0-9]+\\.{1}\t");

for(var o in arr) {

  var find = myRe.exec(arr[o].competense);
  
  if(find) {
  
    newArr.push(arr[o]);
    
  }
}`

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо. То что нужно.